# Верстка сайта, размеры div

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Столкнулся с такой проблемой при верстке сайта. Запускал во всех браузерах, этот маленький пропуск видно везде, но только при 100%. При отдалении или приближении окна браузера этот пробел пропадает. 
Пробовал и длину указывать как у материнского div'а, так и приписывать ему "display: block". Ничего не помогло.

upd upd: добавил код и тест изображение, под желтым фоном у бордера почему то появляется пробел, повторюсь, при отдалении и приближении окна его нет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы действительно считаете, что это этому огрызку изображения можно понять, в чем проблема и о каком пропуске идет речь? Выложите код и более подробно объясните, в чем проблема

Comment: Подробнее есть куда. Код в студию, иначе вопрос будет закрыт.

Comment: @andreymal обновил вопрос

Comment: Вы предлагаете нам код вручную с картинки перепечатывать? Код должен быть текстом.

Comment: И, разумеется, помимо css-кода должен быть и html-код, вместе составляющие минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

В любом браузере пользуемом нажмите F12 затем Ctrl+Shift+C и наведите на Ваш фантом - увидите, где он расположен или чем генерируется - и далее уже разберетесь с ним. На картинке в FireFox.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]